# Dotnet Core 2 EF code first, database migrations on cloud foundry

Tags: deployment, .net-core, entity-framework-core, cloud-foundry, entity-framework-migrations

I use in my a project (using .Net core 2, EF core 2.1) according to [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/migrations#introduction-to-migrations) the code first approach.
Everything works and now I would like to deploy my application on the cloud foundry, but the problem is, that there is no dotnet cli to run command lines like `dotnet ef database update`. So my question is, how should I deploy my project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use in Startup, this will apply migrations to your database when your app starts running:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
                using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
                {
                    var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<YourDbContext>();
                    context.Database.Migrate();
                }
}
```

Comment: this can easily be destructive though. you have to be careful. test migrations locally first.